# Get the min element from a list of dates (operator is not a function [tycon mismatch])

Tags: sml, ml

I wonder, how can I find the oldest date in a list:

```
fun the_oldest_date(date_list: (int * int * int) list) = 
  let
    (*it might be useful*)
    fun older_date(date1: (int * int * int), date2: (int * int * int)) = 
      if #1 date1 < #1 date2 andalso
         #2 date1 < #2 date2 andalso
         #3 date1 < #3 date2
      then date1
      else date2
  in
    if null date_list
    then NONE
    else SOME older_date(hd date_list, the_oldest_date(tl date_list))
  end
```

I'd like not to use any library functions here, only recursion and standard ML facilities. 
And I get the error

```
Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch]
  operator: ((int * int * int) * (int * int * int) -> int * int * int) option
in expression:
  (SOME older_date) (hd date_list,the_oldest_date (tl date_list))
/usr/lib/smlnj/bin/sml: Fatal error -- Uncaught exception Error with 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex,

your older_date function is not working right. You didn't consider two dates that have same year and/or month (ie. (1,1,1) and (1,1,2)). And finally this function should return `bool` not a `(int * int * int)`.

Finding a maximum is a bit trickier, so you should try to find the maximum of a list tail and then compare it with a head.

I hope this helps. And my code is:

```
fun the_oldest_date(date_list : (int * int * int) list) : (int * int * int) option = 
    let 
        fun older_date(date1:(int * int * int) , date2:(int * int * int)) : bool =
            if #1 date1 < #1 date2 
            then true
            else if #1 date1 = #1 date2
                 then if #2 date1 < #2 date2 
                      then true
                      else if #2 date1 = #2 date2
                           then if #3 date1 < #3 date2 
                                then true
                                else false
                           else false
                 else false  
     in        
        if null date_list 
        then NONE
        else
            let
                val prevMax = the_oldest_date(tl date_list)
            in
                if prevMax = NONE
                then SOME(hd date_list)
                else if older_date(hd date_list, valOf prevMax)
                     then SOME(hd date_list)
                     else prevMax
            end
    end
```

Comment: have you tried it? it says Error: operator is not a function [tycon mismatch] -- the_oldest_date([(2005,1,11), (2006,1,11)])

Comment: After loading file to sml I am  getting: val the_oldest_date = fn : (int * int * int) list -> (int * int * int) option
val it = () : unit

Comment: And after: the_oldest_date([(2005,1,11), (2006,1,11)]); I am getting: val it = SOME (2005,1,11) : (int * int * int) option

Comment: by the way, instead of `then if #3 date1 < #3 date2 
                                then true
                        else false` you could say `then #3 date1 < #3 date2 
                                `

Answer (score 1):

There are three issues.

First, you forgot brackets in

```
SOME older_date(hd date_list, the_oldest_date(tl date_list))
```

as SML tells you, this is interpreted as

```
(SOME older_date) (hd date_list, the_oldest_date(tl date_list))
```

and `SOME older_date` isn't a function.

Since `older_date` has type

```
(int * int * int) * (int * int * int) -> int * int * int
```

`SOME older_date` has type

```
((int * int * int) * (int * int * int) -> int * int * int) option
```

You should make it

```
SOME (older_date(hd date_list, the_oldest_date(tl date_list)))
```

(Function application associates to the left, so `a b c` means `(a b) c`, *not* `a (b c)`.

Except that this won't work either, because of the second issue.

The second issue is that `the_oldest_date` returns an `int * int * int option`, while `older_date` expects an `int * int * int` (you might want to consider a more specific data type - it's impossible to tell which part of a date is which here).
You'll need to check the result of `the_oldest_date (tl date_list)` to see if it actually returns something before you pass it to the comparison function.

The third issue is that your date comparison is a bit funky.
As far as I can see, you claim that there is no date *ever* that is earlier than January 1st, 2014.
I have my doubts about that.

Answer (score 0):

sml is complaining because you're using option type. `'a option = NONE | SOME of 'a` i.e. the argument in `(SOME older_date)...` should be a single element, which should be your oldest date.

Comment: even when I don't use them, it complains.

Comment: As far as I can tell, your older_date function should take date_list as an argument and spit out the oldest date. So you have SOME (older_date date_list).

Comment: even when I don't use them, it complains

Comment: Are you sure your older_date function is giving you the oldest date? Take it outside the the_oldest_date function and check if it is truly giving you the oldest_date among date_list.

Answer (score 0):

ok. first things first, remove the last `andalso` inside `older_date`.

Comment: so so, but you have to start somewhere. next: `the_oldest_date` is returning an option inside which there's a call to `older_date`. so far so good.

Comment: but how it intends to return it? by calling `SOME`. that `SOME` will need some parentheses because compiler complains `it's an operator not a function`, try `SOME (older date (...))`. in the meanwhile `older_date` that expects to be called with 2 dates, i.e. 2 `(int*int*int)`, or as sml is showing it `(int * int * int) * (int * int * int)` has been fed with the first one as a date indeed, but the second one is yet another call to `the_oldest_date`, which will return an `option`. have we almost forgot by now that `older_date` expects another `(int*int*int)` there and not an `option`?

Comment: if so, then let's put another twist to the plot and extract from the said `option` its content by using `valOf` on it: `valOf(the_oldest_date (...))`. so complete correction for the last `else` is `else SOME (older_date (hd date_list, valOf(the_oldest_date (tl date_list))))`. that will compile.

Answer (score 0):

I'd convert each date to an epoch, then compare the ints. Something like

```
epoch = (#1 date-1) * 365 + daysBeforeMonth(#2 date) + (#3 date)
```